# MongoDB: How to query documents within a set amount of time between each other

Tags: mongodb

So I have a bit of a unique problem. How do I query documents that have a `date` timestamp that are within, say, 1 second of each other? I plan to move and refactor documents to another collection, where documents that are created within 1 second of each other will be merged as one document.

where, in this example:

```
{
    id: 1,
    date: ISODate("2020-09-24T02:24:45.631Z"),
    data: ...
},
{
    id: 2,
    date: ISODate("2020-09-24T02:24:45.632Z"),
    data: ...
},
{
    id: 3,
    date: ISODate("2020-09-24T02:30:00.000Z"),
    data: ...
},
```

IDs 1 and 2 will be queried as they are within 1 second of each other, and ID #3 is not. I plan to write a script that can execute this.

Comment: So, what would be the date value when the IDs 1 and 2 are merged?

Comment: @prasad_ Any from the two, actually. It shouldn't matter in my case

Comment: What happens when there are three documents which are 1 second apart? What happens to the other data, how is it merged?

Comment: I'm wondering how to handle the following case: Imagine in an hour every half a seconds there is an event, so when i cluster them should i cluster ALL of those events into 1? even though between the first and last there is a 30min gap?

Comment: @prasad_ Then 3 of those documents will be queried :D

Comment: @TomSlabbaert yup, that's right!